Remove the user-ID in a share-question link
When you click "share" to permalink an answer, it displays the following:

This user ID is used for certain badges. As of 2011, a staff member alleged that they were not used for tracking in any form, while another left the door open that it might be used in tracking. (Official 2024 clarification on this would be appreciated). Regardless, they are also a privacy risk if people don't remember to trim the user ID. (This is particularly an issue for mod messages, which are intended to be anonymous.) Here's an annecdote where the share-link compromised the paper-refereeing process.
The answers to that previously-mentioned question contain many good mockups that give the option to remove tracking:

Two text boxes
Two share buttons
An "anonymize link" button
Make the tracking item a query parameter, to make it clear that it's not an integral part of the link
Make it a user-profile setting

And this question suggests anonymizing or hashing it so that each userID-answerID pairing is unique and identifiable.
These are all great ideas, but they involve dev time, so they've lingered in limbo for ages. Here's one that doesn't.

Just remove it.
We don't need tracking.
It doesn't matter if it's nigh-universal across the web, or if they provide nice analytics data. If Stack Overflow (company) respects its users, it shouldn't be trying to track them off-site.
How will users get those badges!
They won't!! Just like there isn't a badge for "write a well-received question while on the toilet", because it's none of SE's business whether an answer was written while taking a dump or not.
These badges were something that got added because it seemed cool in 2011. But reevaluating them in 2024, it's clear that they no longer the justify the privacy invasion.

animuson's suggestion of "a setting to disable including the user Id network wide by default is valid so that users can make sure they are protected if they so desire" seems like a better feature request than completely removing the feature for everyone. Personally, I do intentionally share links that contain my user id under certain circumstances and also omit it when needed. Though I have a UserScript (Optionally Anonymised Short Links) which makes it easier to choose when to include my user id or not.

No good Meta post goes unpunished. Here, we have a well-written post, complete with good citations, proposing a solution to something widely acknowledged as a legitimate problem. And just because other users disagree with that solution, the author is being punished with downvotes and decreasing reputation, which left unchecked, will compromise their ability to participate on Meta at all. This is what is wrong with Meta. (The comment above falls in the category ‘involve dev time, so they've lingered in limbo for ages’, so one could argue it doesn’t really count.)

What about those of us who like them shiny badges?

@BrianDrake as long as Separate vote in favour and against a feature request hasn't been implemented, then unfortunately voting is different on meta still applies.

@BrianDrake while I appreciate the concern, IIRC +1's are worth more rep than -1s, so it's pretty difficult to go negative. Also (as evidenced by my disdain for badges and the fact that I clearly don't understand exactly how rep works) I don't really care about rep as long as I stay above the can-leave-comments threshold. On meta, disagreement is signalled with a down vote and so I don't take downvotes here personally.

(e.g. my understanding is that this currently stands at +3/-11, which nets me +30 rep and -22 rep, so in total I'm +8 points in the black--it'd be pretty hard to lose significant rep on meta posts.)

An opt-in workaround is to use this userscript: Optionally Anonymised Short Links

Wait, wasn't there a profile option to disable including the ID?

Kaia the bigger issue is (eventual) question bans, which can kick in despite net positive reputation but negative net votes. I’m pretty sure that’s what @BrianDrake is referring to with “will compromise their ability to participate on Meta at all”

@fyrepenguin Question bans on Meta are very hard to get. (As someone who's gotten one) it takes a lot of a terribly received questions with no well received questions to get q-banned here. Even if you do, a few correct answers to simple support questions will usually get you out of your ban

@Starship I’ve not commented on the difficulty of question bans nor that of getting out of them. Just that positive net rep is not the only thing that matters.

@fyrepenguin My point is that negative net rep or close to it is about how much you need in order to be getting a q-ban.

@Starship I've accepted it because it seems like the overwhelming community consensus and I want to reflect that this is "a settled matter". However, I disagree with the community consensus it represents (and, this being meta, have downvoted accordingly :P).

FWIW I understand the concern very much. I regularly remove tracking ids from links that I share. I don't usually do it for Stack Exchange links because I happen to work here and know that we're not doing anything nefarious with that info, but the concern is completely understandable. +1

The vast majority of users in the vast majority of cases don't care very much about their user ID being in a link. There is no reason they all need to be prevented from earning these badges.
If you happen to be in some situation where you don't want your user ID in a link your sharing, just remove the ID. Or, alternatively, just copy the URL you are currently on (for answers this will usually send you to the question, though).
If you are really really worried about this, just use the Optionally Anonymised Short Links user script.

accepting--this seems like a fair representation of consensus.

"Or, alternatively, just copy the URL you are currently on (for answers this will usually send you to the question, though)" I have a userscript that purposely changes all post links on the page and window.location to the short links with my user ID in it. because I like it that way :P
